# Next-Auth Azure Active Directory Issue

Tags: next.js, azure-active-directory, next-auth

I'm working on NextJS and we want to use Azure Active Directory for login with Next-auth. I added this code below and when we load the app it redirect and show login button once we click on that Sign In Azure Active Dictatory button it shows Microsoft login screen and after successful login it redirect to this URL **api/auth/signin?error=OAuthCallback** and shows Login Button again and with a error try using different account **Try signing in with a different account.** ?

#### pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts

```
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";


export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: "",
      clientSecret: "",
      tenantId: "",
      authorization: { params: { scope: "openid profile user.Read email" } },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      // IMPORTANT: Persist the access_token to the token right after sign in
      if (account) {
        token.idToken = account.id_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

#### Inside home component we have this

```
export default function Home() {

  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  console.log(session)
  console.log(status)

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    if (!session && status !== "unauthenticated") {
      signIn();
    }
  }


return (
<div>Home</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, I was missing the client secret key in .ENV. When I added this environment variable in .ENV file it starts works

NEXTAUTH_SECRET=your_secret_key

Answer (score 0):

*I made some changes in the Home.tsx code and was able to login next js with Azure Active Directory.*

**components/Home.tsx :**

```js
import { signIn, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const Home = () => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  if (status === 'loading') {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {session ? (
        <div>
          <p>Welcome, {session.user?.name}!</p>
          <p>Email: {session.user?.email}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>You are not signed in.</p>
          <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in with Azure AD</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**pages/_app.tsx :**

```js
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import '../styles/globals.css'; 

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

I added the below **URL** in the app registration **Redirect URI**,

> http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/azure-ad

[image]

And Granted the admin consent for Contoso in **User.Read** as below,

[image]

**Output :**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

I got below with the above output **URL** in the browser. Then, I click on **Sign in with Azure AD** as below,

[image]

I click on **Sign in with Azure Active Directory** as below,

[image]

I chose my account for sign in as below,

[image]

***Then, I signed in with my account and got my email address as below.***

[image]